# How to change date format (from yyyy-MM-DD to yyyy-MM)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to change date format from `yyyy-MM-dd` to `yyyy-MM`.

Ultimately I want to be able to sum and group by month. So far the only working solution I found is adding `concat(year(join_data["firstVisit"]), lit("-"), month(join_data["firstVisit"])).alias('firstVisitMonth')` in my select statement but then it return the column as a string and I can't sort it correctly.

Comment: use : `date_trunc("month", join_data["firstVisit"]).cast("date")` returns a date truncated to month.

Answer (score 1):

Try `date_format`:

```
date_format(join_data["firstVisit"], 'yyyy-MM')
```

Comment: I speak too quickly. this is also returned as a string

Comment: @SimonBreton you can try  `to_date(trunc(join_data["firstVisit"], 'month'))`